# How to upgrade eclipse from Galileo to Helios in Ubuntu 10.10 via "Help->Install New Software..."

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, dependencies, upgrade, helios

I know the direct-download method but still want to make the upgrade with the help of Eclipse. When I plan to do so, the following errors rise:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>
> > Software being installed: Eclipse SDK 3.6.2.M20110210-1200 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)
> >
> > Software currently installed: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
> >
> > Only one of the following can be installed at once:
> >
> > > Equinox Provisioning Publisher 1.1.2.v20100824-2220 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher 1.1.2.v20100824-2220)
> > >
> > > Equinox Provisioning Publisher 1.1.0.v20100513 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher 1.1.0.v20100513)
> > >
> > > Equinox Provisioning Publisher 1.0.1.R35x_20100105 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher 1.0.1.R35x_20100105)
> >
> > Cannot satisfy dependency:
> >
> > > From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.2 (Eclipse Platform 3.5.2)
> > >
> > > To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher [1.0.1.R35x_20100105]
> >
> > Cannot satisfy dependency:
> >
> > > From: Equinox p2 Provisioning 2.0.1.r361_v20100903-897HFa-FX0z-z-ntoaavz0JPX628 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.0.1.r361_v20100903-897HFa-FX0z-z-ntoaavz0JPX628)
> > >
> > > To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher [1.1.2.v20100824-2220]
> >
> > Cannot satisfy dependency:
> >
> > > From: Eclipse SDK 3.6.2.M20110210-1200 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)
> > >
> > > To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.0.1.r361_v20100903-897HFa-FX0z-z-ntoaavz0JPX628]

I am using http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.6/ . It seems that I need a newer `Equinox Provisioning Publisher` to make a successful upgrade. But after a rough search I did not find much information. So what should I do now? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://plosquare.blogspot.com/2011/04/fix-for-cannot-complete-install-because.html), the only lines that really matter from that error output are the last ones.

Cannot satisfy dependency:

```
From: Eclipse SDK 3.6.2.M20110210-1200 (org.eclipse.sdk.ide 3.6.2.M20110210-1200)

To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.0.1.r361_v20100903-897HFa-FX0z-z-ntoaavz0JPX628]
```

I had this problem too and was unable to resolve it without first uninstalling everything and following [this](http://brohaveyouseenmysocks.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/how-to-install-eclipse-sdk-3-6-2-helios-with-subclipse-and-the-marketplace-client/) method to get it all rolling (That's a link to my blog where I mashed together all the guides that helped me get it installed).

Good luck!